# Search a string and check if it is incomplete in array of string

Tags: c#, string, linq, asp.net-core

I have a simple array of strings example given below returning from an API, which we do not have a much control.

I am searching for "ABC HG" or "ABCHG".
This is incomplete string as it should be either ABC HGL or any other characters after "HG" if you see in the array example. This is an API, which gives me all results even it is a partial string. However, this string example search should be considered as incomplete string, and should not give me any result. How do I do this through linq or elegant way?

```
string[] strings = {"This is not ABC HGL",
"I am going to ABC HGL",
"What is ABC HGT",
"Excellent ABC HGU"}
```

I simply need to find for a search string, if it is an incomplete string and do not result  anything.

**Please note the input search string can be with or without space but the array results is always with space
**

Comment: Is the words always at the end of the string?

Comment: @AbhishekDutt I think we both know what he meant, but I have edited the question to be clear ;)

Comment: Thanks, It is not necessary, it is at the end - it could be "I am ABC HGU in this world"

Comment: Thanks Moo - Juice - did not realise my mistake there.

Comment: It should not give me any result if it is incomplete, Or I just need to find out a way, that this is an incomplete string - so I can ask them to complete it as an error

Comment: I am thinking to check if it exists and then if it does, check the length of string to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var searchStr = "ABC HG";
string[] strings =
{
    "This is not ABC HGL",
    "I am going to ABC HG.",
    "What is ABC Hg",
    "ABC HG is excellent ",
    "I am ABC HGU in this world"
};

var results = strings.Where(x => x.StartsWith($"{searchStr} ") ||
                                 x.Contains($" {searchStr} ") ||
                                 x.Contains($".{searchStr} ") ||
                                 x.Contains($" {searchStr}.") ||
                                 x.EndsWith($" {searchStr}")).ToList();
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
I am going to ABC HG.
ABC HG is excellent
```

---

**Edit: Improved original answer**

Updated the code to include:

- matching strings between space
- ignoring special characters such as commas, periods and others

For example searching for`ABCHGL`to yield a match for `-ABC HGL.`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var searchStr = "ABC HG";
    string[] strings =
    {
        "My friend name is Mr.ABC HG.",
        "Where is ABC HGL.",
        "Email is ABC@ABC .HG",
        "Who is ABC HGLM",
        "I am going to (ABC HG)",
        "What is ABC Hg",
        "ABC HG is excellent ",
        ",ABC HG! is not coming",
        "I am ABC HGU in this world"
    };

    var results = strings.Where(x => IsMatched(x, searchStr) ||
                                     MatchBtwSpace(x, searchStr)).ToList();
    foreach (var result in results)
        Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private static bool IsMatched(string line, string query)
{
    if (line.Contains(query))
    {
        // inject whitespace at start and end of line to reduce complexity
        line = $" {line} ";
        int queryStartIndex = line.IndexOf(query);
        int queryEndIndex = queryStartIndex + query.Length - 1;

        // check if between query contains letters or numbers
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(line[queryStartIndex - 1]) ||
            char.IsLetterOrDigit(line[queryEndIndex + 1]))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool MatchBtwSpace(string str, string query)
{
    // split line to words
    var words = str.Split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 == words.Length)
            break;
        var match = IsMatched($"{words[i]}{words[i + 1]}", query);
        if (match)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Output:

```cs
searchStr = "ABC HG" OR "ABCHG"
//My friend name is Mr.ABC HG.
//I am going to (ABC HG)
//ABC HG is excellent
//,ABC HG! is not coming

searchStr = "ABC@ABC.HG"
//Email is ABC@ABC .HG
```

Comment: This is not giving me correct result - when I tested on the array of strings above

Comment: @matrixnew Thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer, I believe now it should give correct results. Let me know if it still does not give correct results.

Comment: Sorry, can you amend this code, in this way that It can use the search str without space too but the array still have space in it for example, If I search with ABCHGL, it should still yeild me results?

Comment: @matrixnew I included searching for `ABCHGL` and yielding results. Let me know if it works.

Comment: There are other delimeters than just `' '` and `'.'`. What about `'('`, `')'`, `','`, `'\r'`, ...
This is not the best approach.

Comment: There is one more variant have come up - ABCH - it should not return any value please if you can help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Linq would be appropriate for this. The approach i would take is to check if the search string exist, and then check if the characters to the left and right of the search target are white spaces. So something like this:

```
public bool IsMatch(string stringToCheck, string searchString);
int index = 0;
while( index < stringToCheck.Length){
  index = stringToCheck.IndexOf(searchString, index);
  if(index < 0) return false;
  var indexBefore = index - 1;
  var indexAfter = index + searchString.Length ;
  var hasWhitespaceBefore = indexBefore < 0 ||   !char.IsLetter(stringToCheck[indexBefore];
  var hasWhitespaceAfter = indexAfter >= stringToCheck.Length || !char.IsLetter(stringToCheck[indexBefore];
  if( hasWhitespaceBefore && hasWhitespaceAfter) return true;
  index++;
}
```

Note that code is untested. Be aware of of-by-one errors!

Comment: Instead of `char.IsWhiteSpace(...)`, consider `!char.IsLetter(...)`.

Comment: Also, consider that the `searchString` might appear more than once in the `stringTocheck`, and maybe the first one isn't a full match, but an other one is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this

```
var inputStrings = new string[]
{
    "asdfasdf ABD DGT world",
    "asdfasdf ABD DGL world",
    "asdfasdf ABD DG world",
    "asdfasdf ABD DG",
    "asdfasdf ABD DGL",
    "asdfasdf ABD DGT"
};
var searchText = "ABD DG";
var regex = new Regex($@"{searchText}(?!\S)");
    
var matchingStrings = inputStrings.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x));
// Returns "asdfasdf ABD DG world" and "asdfasdf ABD DG"
```

Comment: I tested this one - is working perfectly, thanks

Comment: One Question here -: In some case, I do not have space in between ABD DGT, they are like this ABDDGT (similar to postcode examples). In that case, this is failing, can you please help?

Comment: What I meant is - the array still have ABD DGL, ABD DGT, but we can input search text as ABDDGL or ABDDGT. And when I search input without space, it is failing.

Comment: Are the letters always in captial casing?

Comment: they can be small or capital casing in search input

Comment: You can change `var searchText = "ABD DG";` to `var searchText = string.Join(@"\s?","ABDDG".ToArray());`